# Custom login for two different AD Users

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, authentication

I am using **SharePoint 2010** and I want to create **custom login page** for AD users.

There are **two different active directory** users who are logging everyday to site. Now for login, instead of default login prompt, i want to make custom login page of that site.

Is there any way i can create a **single login page** in which both active directory user can login using **same site URL**?

If we extend that site then we can put AD Connection string in both web config file but i do not want to extend the site as it will create two different urls for same site and user will be confused.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you wanting to switch from WIA to FBA? This brings a significant number of challenges.

What I'd recommend is if you _must_ have an FBA login, to use WAP + AD FS in non-claims aware mode. This will allow for multiple forests provided there are trusts in place.

Comment: @TrevorSeward Actually there are lots of user in my application and there is an password expiration policy. so if i have fba login page, we can show him an error regarding his/her password expiration and display a form to reset his/her password. I cant do it with window auth as it just prompt again and again and cant redirect or shows any message. Thanks

Comment: Again, I would strongly recommend not using FBA in SharePoint due to the challenges in doing so. Implement a pre-authentication system that can pass back Windows credentials to SharePoint, such as AD FS.

Comment: Does ADFS allows me to create custom sign in page?

Comment: It allows limited modification, yes. I would suggest looking up how to customize the AD FS login screen which would fall out of scope of this forum.

Comment: Ok Thanks @TrevorSeward